# how to get value of a tag that has no class or id in html agility pack?

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the text value of this a tag:

`<a href="item?id=22513425">67&nbsp;comments</a>`

so i'm trying to get '67' from this. however there are no defining classes or id's.

i've managed to get this far:

```
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> commentsNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0).Where(n => n.HasClass("subtext"));

        var storyComments = commentsNode.Select(n =>
            n.SelectSingleNode("//a[3]")).ToList();
```

this only give me "comments" annoyingly enough.

I can't use the href id as there are many of these items, so i cant hardcord the href

how can i extract the number aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the @href attribute and a dedicated string function :

```
substring-before(//a[@href="item?id=22513425"],"comments")
```

returns 67.

EDIT : Since you can't hardcode all the content of @href, maybe you can use starts-with. XPath 1.0 solution.

Shortest form (+ text has to contain "comments") :

```
substring-before(//a[starts-with(@href,"item?") and text()[contains(.,"comments")]],"c")
```

More restrictive (+ text has to finish with "comments") :

```
substring-before(//a[starts-with(@href,"item?")][substring(//a, string-length(//a) - string-length('comments')+1) = 'comments'],"c")
```

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned that there are multiple items with different hrefs, i cant hard code the href id

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ScrapySharp` nuget which adds in my sample below, (It's possible HtmlAgilityPack offers the same functionality built it, I am just used to ScrapySharp from years ago)

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"C:\desktop\anchor.html"); //I created an html file with your <a> element as the body
    var anchor = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("a").FirstOrDefault();
    if (anchor == null) return;

    var digits = anchor.InnerText.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c));

    Console.WriteLine($"anchor text: {anchor.InnerText} - digits only: {new string(digits.ToArray())}");
```

Output:

[image]